# Follow a moved file to its destination directory

Tags: shell, rename, cd-command

Is there a way to move a file from a directory to another and then cd into the latter in one command? Something like `mv /a/file /another/dir && cd _` but without typing second time the directory path.

Comment: With most shells that use the `readline` library, `Alt-.` (assuming your terminal treats Alt as Meta) is a very handy interactive keyboard shortcut to know.  It runs the `yank-last-arg` readline command, which pastes the last argument to the previous command.  It even cycles when used repeatedly.

Comment: also the environment variable `!$` is the last arg of the last command ran.

Comment: @h3rrmiller Thanks for the tip (didn't know about it)! But I can't use this in a single command :(

Comment: @h3rrmiller `!$` is indeed the last argument of the last command, but it is history expansion syntax, which is completely different from an environment variable.  If you prefer, `_` *IS* a shell variable in `bash` that corresponds to roughly the same thing.  Note that history expansion is typically not enabled in non-interactive shells.

Comment: @jw013 I never knew about `$_` until just now. I guess I've been doing it the hard way until now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some functions for moving and copying files and following them to the destination directory originating from [a thread on the Arch Linux boards](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=697235#p697235):

```
# Follow copied and moved files to destination directory
cpf() { cp "$@" && goto "$_"; }
mvf() { mv "$@" && goto "$_"; }
goto() { [ -d "$1" ] && cd "$1" || cd "$(dirname "$1")"; }
```

You can then {move,copy} and follow a file by issuing:

```
mvf file /dest/dir/
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why did you create the `goto` function instead of just using `cd` in your cpf/mvf functions?

Comment: They aren't my functions; but I would imagine it was for legibility/clarity...

Answer (score 6):

in your `.bashrc`:

```
cpcd() { cp "$1" "$2" && cd "$2"; }
```

thats how i would do it

then you would use `cpcd` as you would use `cp`

```
cpcd blah dir/
```

and it will copy blah to dir and if that was successful it will change directories to dir/

Comment: Although I have to mod my bashrc for it to work it is nice!

Comment: @Gerry: What do you mean "although" - what's wrong with modifying `.bashrc`? In most cases, that is the way you do stuff like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it forwards:

```
mv /a/file /another/dir; cd $_
```

Or you can do it backwards:

```
cd /another/dir; mv /a/file .
```

Your call.

Answer (score 0):

Test this option, try using verbose mv command to extract the directory and then go to the.

```
cd "$(mv -v file directory | grep -o '/.*/')"
```

Comment: @jasonwryan Test this option

Comment: This approach is not very safe or robust and doesn't even save a whole lot of typing.  Avoid parsing file names and treat them as binary blobs.